# passing the props from menucomponent to dishdetails

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im new to react.js and have been facing this issue.Im working on this app dishes where the user clicks one dish and then it is rendered in form a card.The value of dish is passed as a props from menucomponent to DishDetail but in doing so the dish object is always receiving null value for which there is nothing on the screen . please help me with it.im attaching both MenuComponents.js and DishDetail.js
the MenuComponent.js is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import { Media } from 'reactstrap';
import { Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardText, CardBody,CardTitle } from 'reactstrap';
import DishDetail from './DishdetailComponent';


class Menu extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
   
      this.state = {
         selectedDish: null
      };
   }

   onDishSelect(dish) {
      this.setState({ selectedDish: dish});
  }


   render() {
      const menu = this.props.dishes.map((dish) => {
         return(
            <div key={dish.id} className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
               {/* <Media tag="li">
                  <Media left middle>
                        <Media object src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                  </Media>
                  <Media body className="ml-5">
                     <Media heading>{dish.name}</Media>
                     <p>{dish.description}</p>
                  </Media>
               </Media>  */}
               <Card key={dish.id} onClick={() => this.onDishSelect(dish)}>
                  <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                  <CardImgOverlay>
                      <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                  </CardImgOverlay>
                </Card>
            </div>
         );
      });
      

      return(
         <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
               {/* <Media list>
                  {menu}
               </Media> */}
               {menu}
            </div>
            <DishDetail dish={this.state.selectedDish} />
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default Menu;
```

the DishDetail.js is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardText, CardBody,CardTitle } from 'reactstrap';

class DishDetail extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }


    renderDish(dish) {
    
        if (dish != null)
            return(
                <Card>
                    <CardImg top src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                    <CardBody>
                    <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                    <CardText>{dish.description}</CardText>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
            );
            
        else
            return(
                <div></div>
            );
     }

    render() {
        const dish = this.props.selectedDish;
        console.log(dish);
        return(
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                    {this.renderDish(this.props.selectedDish)}
                </div>
                <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default DishDetail;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a property named `dish` to your component but using `selectedDish`.

```js
<DishDetail dish={this.state.selectedDish} />

const dish = this.props.selectedDish;
```

Answer (score 0):

The prop passed to the `DishDetail` component is called `dish`:

```js
// MenuComponent.js

<DishDetail dish={this.state.selectedDish} />
```

However `DishDetail` is expecting a prop with the name `selectedDish`:

```js
// DishDetail.js

const dish = this.props.selectedDish;
{this.renderDish(this.props.selectedDish)}
```

Updating `DishDetail` to use `this.props.dish` will resolve your issue:

```js
const dish = this.props.dish;
{this.renderDish(this.props.dish)}
```

Comment: it does not...but passing selectedDish as a prop in MenuComponents does